# Creating multiple maps from a single layer - ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am looking for an add in for ArcGIS 10.1 to create multiple maps from a single layer that consists of a number of polygons. I have come across such an add in for MapInfo. Is there such an add in available for ArcGIS, or is there a way do this within ArcGIS?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'multiple maps'? Maksim's answer provides a way of making a new map sheet for each polygon, which is one possible interpretation of your question. I'm reading it more as you want to symbolize the same data in different ways. Such as you have counties and you want one map that shows them by median income and another by population. You can add the same data to a map many times and symbolize it differently each time, and you can have multiple dataframes in a single layout that would show such, or you can have multiple mxds with one datafame each. Not sure what your goal is.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Creating Data Driven Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000003n000000), you can cycle through your polygons and have a map of each.